# Applying colors dynamically to table cells in R

Tags: r, colors, dt

I have a data frame in R that looks like this:

[image]

It is 84 rows high and 365 rows wide. The dput is below. What I'm trying to figure out is how to get each cell to change color based on the symbol that's in the cell (also, I don't want to see the column name, row name, or gridlines). I've tried kable, DT, base R, heatmap, and huxtable. The closest I've gotten is with DT:

```
datatable(cover, rownames=FALSE, options = list(dom = 't')) %>% formatStyle(names(cover), backgroundColor=styleEqual(hex$Symbol, hex$Hex))
```

Here's the result from that code:

[image]

I haven't been able to figure out how to also remove the column names (so the columns are only as wide as the symbol) or the gridlines. I'm sure there's a way to do this but I've been spinning my wheels for a couple days so I thought I'd ask the experts. I'm still fairly new with R (I'm a data analyst, not a professional coder). My ultimate goal is for it to look something like this (which was created with Google Sheets conditional formatting):

[image]

dput of the head of the first 10 columns of the data table:

```
structure(list(`2019-01-01` = c("f", "f", "f", "<U+263D>", "<U+263D>", "<U+263D>"), `2019-01-02` = c("<U+270E>", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>"), `2019-01-03` = c("t", "t", "t", "d", "d", "d"), `2019-01-04` = c("d", "d", "d", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>"), `2019-01-05` = c("&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&"), `2019-01-06` = c("<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "&", "&", "&"), `2019-01-07` = c("^", "^", "^", "^", "^", "^"), `2019-01-08` = c("&", "&", "&", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>"), `2019-01-09` = c("<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>"), `2019-01-10` = c("s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

dput of the Symbol to Hex lookup table:

```
structure(list(Symbol = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a","i", "k", "b", "l", "r", "c", "x", "@", "%", "^", "e", "m", "s", "#", "<U+270E>", "&", "<U+2699>", "d", "t", "y", "n", "<U+25C0>", "<U+263D>", "f", "<U+2689>", "<U+2726>", "<U+0394>", "¥", "p", "u", "<U+2326>", "<U+26AF>", "z", "<U+2714>", "o", "+", "v", "g", "<U+262F>", "<U+2724>", "<U+272B>", "<U+2766>", "j", "q", "h", "<U+2665>", "w"), Hex = c("#572433", "#72375D", "#633666", "#803A6B", "#6C3A6E", "#776B98", "#ADA7C7", "#5C7294", "#7B8EAB", "#707DA2", "#555B7B", "#464563", "#0E365C", "#11416D", "#13477D", "#2C597C", "#396987", "#4781A5", "#35668B", "#5A8FB8", "#3B768F", "#4F93A7", "#5BA3B3", "#90C3CC", "#C4DECC", "#7BAC94", "#5B9071", "#396F52", "#044D33", "#313919", "#424D21", "#4C5826", "#72843C", "#94AB4F", "#AEBF79", "#CCD9B1", "#D8E498", "#FFFB8B", "#FDF9CD", "#FFF1AF", "#FDD755", "#FFC840", "#FFBF57", "#FFA32B", "#FF8B00", "#F67F00", "#F27842", "#FF836F", "#E96A67", "#FF7992", "#E74967", "#BA4A4A", "#B33B4B", "#970B23", "#87071F", "#A7132B", "#913546")), row.names = c(NA, -57L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Index = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Color = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), `Color name` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), Symbol = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), Hex = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here's the code I'm using per the comments below. It worked last week but now it isn't. I've determined through going line by line that value2 isn't rendering properly, but I've checked it against the code provided and it looks exactly the same. I'm calling the dataset "cover" and the color table "hex".

```
hexcol <- hex$Hex
names(hexcol) <- hex$Symbol
bcol <- function(x){hexcol[as.character(x)]}

x <- cover %>%
  dplyr::mutate(row.id = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(key = "key", value = "value", -row.id) %>%
  mutate(value2 = "  ", value2 = cell_spec(value2, background = mapply(bcol, value), color = mapply(bcol, value))) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  spread(key = key, value = value2) %>%
  select(-row.id) %>%
  kable(format = "html", escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)
x2 <- gsub("<thead>.*</thead>", "", x)
x3.splits <- unlist(str_split(x2, pattern = "\n"))
x3.cols <- str_extract(x3.splits, pattern = "#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}")
x3.vals <- str_extract(x3.splits, pattern = "(a-Z0-9)+")

# cycle through each row of HTML code to find and replace any value with HTML/CSS code to color the background of that specific cell
for (i in 1:length(x3.splits)){
  if (!is.na(x3.cols[i])){
    x2 <- gsub(pattern = x3.splits[i], 
               replacement = paste0('<td style="text-align:center; background-color: ', x3.cols[i], '; border-top: 1px solid ', 
                                    x3.cols[i], ';"><span style="margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px">   </span></td>'), x = x2)
  }
}
```

Here's the session info:
[image]

Comment: I ran the code you posted on my device and it still seems to work for me - when you say it doesn't render, does it throw any sort of error or are the colors not showing up in RStudio?

Comment: The colors just aren't showing up in RStudio. When I run x2, it just shows a bunch of lines with no background.

Comment: can you run `sessionInfo()` and paste the results into your question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `kableExtra` package? I was able to do the following which I think does what you're hoping to do using this package as well as some HTML syntax/regular expression substitutions. Let me know if this doesn't seem to work for you though!

```
library(kableExtra)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magick)
library(webshot)

dat <- structure(list(`2019-01-01` = c("f", "f", "f", "<U+263D>", "<U+263D>", "<U+263D>"), `2019-01-02` = c("<U+270E>", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>"), `2019-01-03` = c("t", "t", "t", "d", "d", "d"), `2019-01-04` = c("d", "d", "d", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>"), `2019-01-05` = c("&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&"), `2019-01-06` = c("<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "&", "&", "&"), `2019-01-07` = c("^", "^", "^", "^", "^", "^"), `2019-01-08` = c("&", "&", "&", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>"), `2019-01-09` = c("<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>"), `2019-01-10` = c("s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

col.tab <- structure(list(Symbol = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a","i", "k", "b", "l", "r", "c", "x", "@", "%", "^", "e", "m", "s", "#", "<U+270E>", "&", "<U+2699>", "d", "t", "y", "n", "<U+25C0>", "<U+263D>", "f", "<U+2689>", "<U+2726>", "<U+0394>", "¥", "p", "u", "<U+2326>", "<U+26AF>", "z", "<U+2714>", "o", "+", "v", "g", "<U+262F>", "<U+2724>", "<U+272B>", "<U+2766>", "j", "q", "h", "<U+2665>", "w"), Hex = c("#572433", "#72375D", "#633666", "#803A6B", "#6C3A6E", "#776B98", "#ADA7C7", "#5C7294", "#7B8EAB", "#707DA2", "#555B7B", "#464563", "#0E365C", "#11416D", "#13477D", "#2C597C", "#396987", "#4781A5", "#35668B", "#5A8FB8", "#3B768F", "#4F93A7", "#5BA3B3", "#90C3CC", "#C4DECC", "#7BAC94", "#5B9071", "#396F52", "#044D33", "#313919", "#424D21", "#4C5826", "#72843C", "#94AB4F", "#AEBF79", "#CCD9B1", "#D8E498", "#FFFB8B", "#FDF9CD", "#FFF1AF", "#FDD755", "#FFC840", "#FFBF57", "#FFA32B", "#FF8B00", "#F67F00", "#F27842", "#FF836F", "#E96A67", "#FF7992", "#E74967", "#BA4A4A", "#B33B4B", "#970B23", "#87071F", "#A7132B", "#913546")), row.names = c(NA, -57L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Index = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Color = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), `Color name` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), Symbol = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), Hex = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

color_mapper <- col.tab$Hex
names(color_mapper) <- col.tab$Symbol
c_func <- function(x){
  color_mapper[as.character(x)]


}

x <- dat %>%
  mutate(row.id = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(key = "key", value = "value", -row.id) %>%
  mutate(value2 = "  ",
         value2 = cell_spec(value2, background = mapply(c_func, value), color = mapply(c_func, value))
         ) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  spread(key = key, value = value2) %>%
  select(-row.id) %>%
  kable(format = "html", escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)

x2 <- gsub("<thead>.*</thead>", "", x)

x3.splits <- unlist(str_split(x2, pattern = "\n"))
x3.cols <- str_extract(x3.splits, pattern = "#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}")
x3.vals <- str_extract(x3.splits, pattern = "(a-Z0-9)+")

## cycle through each row of HTML code to find and replace any value with
## HTML/CSS code to color the background of that specific cell
for (i in 1:length(x3.splits)){
  if (!is.na(x3.cols[i])){
    x2 <- gsub(
      pattern = x3.splits[i],
      replacement = paste0('<td style="text-align:center; background-color: ', x3.cols[i], '; border-top: 1px solid ', x3.cols[i], ';"><span style="margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px">   </span></td>'),
      x = x2
    )
  }
}
x2 %>%
  save_kable("my_image.png")
```

With the PNG output: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This did eventually render, but it does take a long time to run. Is there anything I can do to make it more efficient (take less time to process)? Also, I notice that kable has it rendering in HTML. I forgot to mention this earlier, but I'm trying to render it to a PDF using rmarkdown. Is there a way to reduce the size of the whole thing so it fits on the width of the page?

Comment: It looks like you can [follow the instructions here](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/save_kable_and_as_image.html) to set up `kableExtra` to save the table output directly as a PNG image or PDF. I think I'd recommend saving as a PNG or using the `as_image()` function to render directly in rmarkdown. I'll update my code to do this, but you'll need to make sure to install the proper dependencies (`webshot` and `magick`) as well as [GhostScript](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) if you're using a Windows device.

Comment: Ok, it was working (slowly) last week and now I'm using the same code and for some reason the formatting on value2 isn't rendering. I tried pasting in my code but it's too long? How can I do that in comments.

Comment: You can edit your original question - or add to the bottom of your question with the updated issue(s)

Comment: Thank you! I've added to my original question.

Comment: So, I took a look at this again. x (as defined in your code above) is rendering almost how I'd like it, but the full cell isn't filled (so it looks like a bunch of vertical lines, that are the correct colors). I tried going all the way through to x2, but it just doesn't render. It doesn't throw an error, but I let it run for at least 30-45 minutes and it never finished. Is there another way to fill the color to the whole cell than the x2 process?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example using `huxtable` (I'm the package author):

```
tmp <- structure(list(`2019-01-01` = c("f", "f", "f", "<U+263D>", "<U+263D>", "<U+263D>"), `2019-01-02` = c("<U+270E>", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>"), `2019-01-03` = c("t", "t", "t", "d", "d", "d"), `2019-01-04` = c("d", "d", "d", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>"), `2019-01-05` = c("&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&"), `2019-01-06` = c("<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "&", "&", "&"), `2019-01-07` = c("^", "^", "^", "^", "^", "^"), `2019-01-08` = c("&", "&", "&", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>", "<U+270E>"), `2019-01-09` = c("<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>", "<U+2699>"), `2019-01-10` = c("s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

ht <- as_hux(tmp)
ht <- map_background_color(ht, by_values("<U+270E>" = "red", "<U+2699>" = "green"))
```

I haven't used your exact symbol table. If it is large, you might want to do something like `do.call(by_values, my_symbols)` where `my_symbols` would be something like `list("1" = "#572433", ...)`.

Comment: I tried a very basic version of this, as you mentioned above, to see if it would work. "pattern" in my code is what you're defining as tmp above. I expected that it would change all the "k" symbols to a background color, but it didn't change the color at all. `ht <- as_hux(pattern)
ht <- map_background_color(ht, by_values("k" = "#94AB4F"))`

Comment: Do I need to add all colors/symbol mappings at once for it to work? I was hoping to validate it with one of them before figuring out the more complex version for all of them.

Comment: I can't debug your problem, because there are no "k"s in your example data. When you run my example, does it work? I copied your example data into the `tmp` variable, as you can see.

Comment: ok, I do see that the red and green are highlighting. How would you suggest best going about applying 57 colors, using a lookup table instead of typing them out like the above? The other issue is that I'd like to narrow the columns down to just the width of one character (particularly those coming through as <U...> codes and turn the font of the symbol the same color as the background.

Comment: Have you tried using `do.call(by_values, my_symbols)` as I suggested? You then need to have `my_symbols` being a `list()` rather than a data frame. The names of the list should be the unicode symbols (you'll need to quote them); the values will be the desired colours. Something like `my_symbols = lookup_table$Hex; names(my_symbols) <- lookup_table$Symbol`, where `lookup_table` is the table you dputted above.

Comment: ok I think I've gotten it working with a mixture of map_background_color and map_text_color. I'm trying to shrink it down now so that it fits on the width of a page. I've been using set_font_size and gotten the font size down to .5, and it's still not fitting. Is there a better way to scale it down than changing the font size?

Comment: Sounds like a new question :-)